# How to count the number of times a value appears in a comma separated cell? (Google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I got data as follows:

[image]

I need a formula that can separate, list and the count each unique word so my output is:

[image]

I am pretty new to google sheet formulas, especially combining several together. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the header "Genre" is in A1 with your comma-separated list running down from A2.

Find two empty columns side by side and place the following in the top cell of the leftmost of those two empty columns:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""),","))),"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY COUNT(Col1) DESC LABEL Col1 'Genre', COUNT(Col1) 'Total'"))`

`FILTER` will cut null cells from `A2:A`, leaving you only with populated cells.

`SPLIT` will split each cell into separate columns at the commas.

`TRIM` will remove leading spaces that existed after commas.

`FLATTEN` will form one column from the results of `SPLIT`.

`QUERY` will give you the unique names and `COUNT` for each in highest-to-lowest (`DESC`ending) order of `COUNT` (with a default of alphabetizing within groups of equal counts) after eliminating any null results of `FLATTEN` and will assign meaningful headers (`LABEL`s) to each column.

Comment: You're welcome, Gian.